xe:djCheckBox unresponsive in Bootstrap 4
xe:djCheckBox does not respond to click when using Bootstrap4 in XPages in Domino 12.0. Change the theme to Bootstrap3 or anything else and it works fine.
Does anyone know of a work around?
I am using xe:djCheckBox as the xp:checkBox version is difficult to align due to the divs and other styling built in.
Any help appreciated.
